# How to convert Invalid date to valid date in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having one Date issue .For Eg if Date format is `2010-10-10 22:10:00.000` this is a valid date and inserts in to my database table.

But if the date format is `2010-10-10 25:10:00.000` which is an invalid date. It checks that the number of hours is greater than 24 than it adds one day to the date and substract 24 hrs from time stamp.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you allowing people to enter freeform dates and times so that they can fill them with nonsense? Do you also plan to cater to `2010-13-13` and `2012-02-31`? Put drop-downs in your forms so users can only select valid dates and times, and validate them before sending them to the server.

While there is likely a really ugly way to parse this junk and support all the rules you want to allow users to break, it is not going to be pretty and in some cases you may actually "correct" a typo and enter a date/time that the user didn't really intend. But because you fixed their mistake for them, they had no idea they even made a mistake.

Comment: Thats true. User always do nonsense. But as developer,we cann't say that it is impossible. User is free to give wrong nonsense data but we have find the solution for that.

Comment: A nice strongly typed parameterized command invocation in your client layer will catch that. Random user Bob entering `2010-10-10 25:10:00.000` does *not* expect it to be retranslated to a valid time + 1 hour